# How can i save many objects in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I get a lot of objects in redax, but only the last one is saved. Each new object replaces the previous one. Can you please tell me how can I save all the objects at once?

I have redux like this [image]

My Reducer

```
const initianalState = {
};

  export const WorldReducer = (state = initianalState, action) => {
 switch (action.type) {
case LOAD_PLANET_NAME: {
  return {
    ...state,
    homeworld: action.data,
    };
  }
default: return state;
  }
};
```

My action

```
 export function loadPlanetName(data) {
return {
type: LOAD_PLANET_NAME,
data
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it will solve the problem

```
case LOAD_PLANET_NAME: {
  return {
    ...state,
    homeworld: [...state.homeworld,action.data],
    };
  }
```